# How's "except such as those (conventions) that" ungrammatical? Why?

Tags: grammaticality

In this [earlier post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/338446), I added to a sentence as follows.

> > 1.1. All the ordinary conventions of a Roman marriage were carried out, except **such as** ***[THOSE (CONVENTIONS) THAT]*** were purely pagan.

Then [Kate Bunting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting) commented

> [Note that in none of your example sentences is the phrase preceded by *except*. It is **except such as those that were** that is wrong.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338494/hows-such-as-those-conventions-that-ungrammatical-why?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment646167_338494)

##### But ["except such as those that”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22except+such+as+those+that%22&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AB5stBgKvieyYERL00HWIc-UEyrwxmQroQ%3A1688778940848&ei=vLioZMS2M--pptQPyJ-smAo&ved=0ahUKEwjEhP7m9_3_AhXvlIkEHcgPC6MQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22except+such+as+those+that%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIIxCKBRAnOg4ILhCKBRDHARCvARCRAjoOCC4QigUQxwEQ0QMQkQI6DQguEIoFELEDEIMBEEM6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToECCMQJzoHCAAQigUQQzoICAAQigUQkQI6EwguEIoFELEDEIMBEMcBENEDEEM6BQgAEIAEOgcIABCABBAKOgcILhCABBAKOggIABAWEB4QDzoGCAAQFhAeOhUILhCABBAKEJcFENwEEN4EEOAEGAE6BwghEKABEApKBAhBGABQ0AlYuSdg2ChoBHABeAGAAckEiAHBIJIBCzAuOS43LjEuMC4xmAEAoAEBwAEByAEI2gEGCAEQARgU&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) is written on trustworthy websites! Hence, is my amendment (1.1) TRULY ‘ungrammatical’? If ungrammatic, why?

> [*Commonwealth v. Siemel*, 686 A.2d 899 (Pa.
> Commw. Ct. 1996) (holding that an ordinance prohibiting excessive vegetation, which was
> defined as any grass, weeds, bushes, brush, saplings, or similar vegetation exceeding six inches in height, **`except such as those that`** are planted for useful or ornamental purposes, was a valid exercise of police power)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1591164)<sup>1</sup>

> [Nimmo also makes reference to the aforementioned Proclamation of May 1684, stating that he knows of no rebels within his parish **`except such as those that`** are in the printed fugitive roll.](https://newcumnockhistory.com/key-historical-events/covenanters/covenanters-timeline/1684-interrogations-of-parishioners)

> [The book, according to Dave, has entries, “all in the handwriting of John Z. Leyendecker, **`except such as (those that)`** bear date subsequent to the death of Mr. Leyendecker.”](https://www.lmtonline.com/opinion/editorials/article/Wife-tells-intriguing-Confederate-tale-10088633.php)

> [(3) All transportation facilities and equipment **`except [such as] those that`** are under the jurisdiction of the public service commission of Nevada as public utilities.](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/Statutes/60th/Stats197905.html)

> [He again complains that he “could conceive of no substantial being  **`except such as those that`** I was wont to see with my own eyes” (*conf.* 7, 1, 1).](https://books.google.com/books?id=LJMk5xAopPUC&lpg=PA34&ots=7-ooTfLEFx&dq=%22except%20such%20as%20those%20that%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=%22except%20such%20as%20those%20that%22&f=false)

> [6767. **`Except such as those that`** have had to be bought in by you?   —Yes.](https://books.google.com/books?id=uUZRAQAAMAAJ&lpg=RA2-PA284&ots=JGipi_v8PP&dq=%22except%20such%20as%20those%20that%22&pg=RA2-PA284#v=onepage&q=%22except%20such%20as%20those%20that%22&f=false)

<sup>1</sup>  Thomas, David A., Whither the Public Forum Doctrine: Has this Creature of the Courts Outlived its Usefulness? (April 16, 2010). *Real Property, Probate and Trust Law Journal*, Vol. 44, p. 659 Footnote 84.

Comment: Please [describe your research](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)! For example: Can you categorize "such as" by parts of speech in both your sentence and the example sentences? Do you know what function that phrase serves? Do you know how to categorize "except" in your sentence? Not only are you expected to describe your research when posting a question, but I'm also pretty sure that in this case doing so will help you get a much better answer, or at least save answerers the effort of explaining what you may already know.

Comment: What KateBunting told you is correct. The syntax of *All .. except **such as were** purely pagan* is a bit formal / dated, but it's fine (it means ***those that were***). And ***Your amended version (1.1) is ungrammatical.***

Comment: Note that in none of your example sentences is the phrase preceded by _except_. It is **except such as those that were** that is wrong.

Comment: "Except" should be normally be followed by a thing or list of what you are excluding: "except such as were purely pagan" means everything that was not purely pagan ("such" is a pronoun and it's limited by the as-clause). Now think about "except such as those conventions that were purely pagan": what do you think this means? Is it excluding all pagan things, some pagan things, some non pagan things and some pagan things, or what? You wrote it, so you should know what it means.

Comment: @KateBunting Please see edits in my question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please see edits in my question.

Comment: See FumbleFingers' excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Dated phrasing**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except%20such%20as%20are%2Cexcept%20such%20as%20those%20that%2Cexcept%20those%20that%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=1980&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
> *[blanket statement] except **such as** are [the exceptions]*

> [**Current phrasing**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except%20such%20as%20are%2Cexcept%20such%20as%20those%20that%2Cexcept%20those%20that%20are&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
> *[blanket statement] except **those that** are [the exceptions]*

> **Non-idiomatic combined phrasing**
> *[blanket statement] except **such as those that** are [the exceptions]*

[image]

[image]

---

Apparently the OP has managed to find several instances of the sequence ***except such as those that*** on the Internet. Even Google Books has [four different published written instances.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22except%20such%20as%20those%20that%22) But those four must be weighed against *thousands* of the "normal" alternatives above. I wouldn't like to say it's completely *ungrammatical* to combine both forms, but it's certainly not "idiomatic" (in the sense of "commonly and naturally used"). I'd call it a "misguided mash-up".